# Postgis - Failed to install it on linux mint mate 17

Tags: postgresql, postgis, linux-mint

I install postgis via `sudo apt-get install postgis postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1`

Then execute `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;` but got following error tip:

```
ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/lib/postgis-2.1.so":
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/lib/postgis-2.1.so: undefined symbol: HeapTupleHeaderGetDatum
```

I am using `postgresql 9.3.4`, and `postgis-2.1`.

I did google for over an hour, but didn't found a solution that really solve my issue.

Any help?

Comment: Linux Mint is not explicitly supported by http://apt.postgresql.org (assuming that's what you're using). Mint seems to be some kind of a hacked Debian / Ubuntu version as far as I can tell. You might be better off with a more stable mainstream distro like Ubuntu.

Comment: @CraigRinger Linux Mint is base on ubuntu, so if things works with ubuntu, it should work with Linux Mint.

Comment: That'd be ideal in theory. In reality, not necessarily true, depending on how much they've changed. As you've just discovered. In this case it looks like your PostGIS was compiled against a newer `postgres` than what you're running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spend another hour, and finally tried to install it from source code, and succeed like a charm, no single issue occur!

Here is the link provide detail steps to install postgis from source code:

http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS21Ubuntu1404src

It also works for my Linux mint mate 17, which is base on ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

The first two hits seem to say basically the same thing to me:

- http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/A9A6BC42-D2E2-471B-BFB0-F6A72EF42911@conundrum.com
- https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/issues/271

It sounds to me like your version of postgis was built against a version of postgresql later than 9.3.4 which included a bugfix that included "HeapTupleHeaderGetDatum". So - upgrade your postgresql (you *do* have something more recent than .4?) and/or make sure you get postgis from the same repo as your postgresql packages.

See if that helps.

Comment: Both postgres & postgis are the newest version that apt-get could find, so I think they match.

Comment: I build from source, and finally succeed to install it.